# On probability and real analysis (Sequence of sets)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $( A_n )_{n \geq 1 } $ be a sequence of sets. IS it true that

$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \chi_{A_n} - \liminf_{n \to \infty} \chi_{A_n} = \chi_{ ( \limsup_n A_n \setminus \liminf_n A_n) } $$

Where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function.

I cannot find counter-examples, so I am trying to prove this. We know the $LHS$ must be $1 - 0 = 1$. Therefore, it remains to show that the $RHS$ is $1$. But, I am stuck trying to show this.

Comment: "We know the LHS must be 1−0=1." Do we? In which sense? After all, these are *functions*, not numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the identity holds. Below are some hints to prove it. Let $A=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$ and $B=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n$.

- Show that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\chi_{A_n}=\chi_A$.
- Show that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\chi_{A_n}=\chi_B$.
- Show that $\chi_A-\chi_B=\chi_{A\setminus B}$ (this one uses that $B\subseteq A$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$ \sup_{k \geq n} \chi_{A_k} (\omega)=\chi_{\cup_{k\geq n}A_k}(\omega)= \chi_{\sup\limits_{k \geq n} A_k} (\omega)  $$

$$ \inf_{k \geq n} \chi_{A_k} (\omega)=\chi_{\cap_{k\geq n}A_k}(\omega)= \chi_{\inf\limits_{k \geq n} A_k} (\omega)  $$